# who can be display value in string on typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

hello I would like to display my min length et max length in terms of the the value entering by user in input

my message is on typescript file who can be get and display that

## **Typescript file**

```
    export class InputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {


  @Input() minlength: number
  @Input() maxlength: number

  @Input() pattern: string
  @Input() required
 
  ValidationHints = {

    required: 'This field is required.',
    minlength: 'Field must be at least '+ this.minlength +' characters long.',
    maxlength: 'Field cannot be more than'+ this.maxlength +'characters long.',
    pattern: 'Please match the requested format.'

  }
```

## **HTML File**

```
<div class="input-container__hints--left">
  <div *ngIf="ngModelRef && ngModelRef.errors && ngModelRef.touched" class="message-coloration-error">
    <div [hidden]="!ngModelRef.errors.required"><i class="mi mi-warning"></i>{{ValidationHints.required}}</div>
    <div [hidden]="!ngModelRef.errors.minlength"><i class="mi mi-warning"></i>{{ValidationHints.minlength}}</div>
    <div [hidden]="!ngModelRef.errors.maxlength"><i class="mi mi-warning"></i>{{ValidationHints.maxlength}}</div>
    <div [hidden]="!ngModelRef.errors.pattern"><i class="mi mi-warning"></i>{{ValidationHints.pattern}}</div>
```

I think my this.minlenght & this.maxlength is not good because I get undefined value

but I dont now what is the syntax or if I forget something before

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the properties directly in the class body and they wouldn't be initialized then anyway.

It's best if you move the construction of the ValidationHints property in the ngOnInit method.

```js
export class InputComponent {


    minlength: number
    maxlength: number

    pattern: string
    required

    ValidationHints: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.ValidationHints = {

            required: 'This field is required.',
            minlength: 'Field must be at least ' + this.minlength + ' characters long.',
            maxlength: 'Field cannot be more than' + this.maxlength + 'characters long.',
            pattern: 'Please match the requested format.'

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I move my validation hints in constructor but he doesn't work

Comment: is display 'Field must be at least unefined characters long.',

Comment: there was a typo in the code I posted, 2 = signs, only one should remain.

Comment: also if not in the constructor then onInit